# PHP Is Parsing interfering with my calculation? Worktime calculation

Tags: php, calculation

i wrote a simple piece of code to calculate from some inputs what some would get for their workings hours but it just seems to work the other way round as i planned it. I did not get to deep into php coding so i still have to work out some early problems.

This script works if i type my example "50" hours. It does not, if i type "49" hours. Then it says i have 11 hours overtime which is incorrect, it should say 9 hours overtime then.

ignore the last piece of script. It's just a dummy right now.

```
        <?php
    // declaration.
    $warbeit = $_POST['wochenarbeit']; //your working hours
    $stundenlohn = 12.50; //what you get paid for hour
    $ueberstunden = 15;  //what you get paid if you work more than 40 hours
    $berechnung = 0;   //how many hours over 40 hours you have - overtime hours
    $auszahlungu = 0;  //what you get paid for your overtime hours
    $auszahlungn = 0; // what you get paid for your hours until overtime
    $gesamtlohn = 0; // what you get paid as sum
    $lohn2 = 0;
    $zuviel = 0;


    if ($warbeit <= 60) {   //if your workingtime is < 60 hours a week  for example 50 hours
        if ($warbeit > 40) {  //if your woringtime is more than 40 hours a week (between 40 and 60) if you take the 50 hours this should work
        $berechnung = (60 - $warbeit);  //how many hours over 40 hours you have - overtime hours - the sum here by 50 hours should be 10 (60-50=10)
        $auszahlungu = ($berechnung * $ueberstunden); //what you get paid for your overtime hours - 10 times 15 should be 150 here
        $auszahlungn = ($warbeit - $berechnung) * $stundenlohn; // what you get paid for your hours until overtime - (50 - 10) * (12.50) - should be 500
        $gesamtlohn = $auszahlungn + $auszahlungu; // what you get paid as sum - 500 + 150 = 650

            echo  "Ihre Überstunden: " . $berechnung . " h<br>";
            echo  "Überstundenabrechnung: " . $auszahlungu . " €<br>";
            echo  "Ihr Gesamtlohn: " . $gesamtlohn . " €<br>";





        }

        else {

                $lohn2 = $warbeit * $stundenlohn;

                    echo  "Ihr Gesamtlohn: " . $lohn2 . " €<br>";

        }

    }
    else {
        $zuviel = (40 * 12.50) + (20 * 15);


        echo   "es werden nur 60 Stunden pro Woche ausgezahlt!";
        echo  "Sie bekommen: " . $zuviel . " €<br>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is your main problem

```
$berechnung = (60 - $warbeit);
```

If you're really going for

```
//how many hours over 40 hours you have - overtime hours
```

Then it should be

```
$berechnung = ($warbeit - 40);
```

The way you have it currently works for 50, but only coincidentally, because 60-50 = 50-40.

Comment: i was really tired as i tried to fix the code but i thought my calculation could be wrong. At least it was as simple as that and nothing related to the sequence the code was running. Thanx :)

Answer (score 0):

you need middle and edge cases

```
if($warbeit == 40){
   process this
}

if ($warbeit > 40 and $warbeit <50) {
    process those
}

if ($warbeit >= 50 and $warbeit <60) {
    process these
}

   if($warbeit == 60){
        process this
}
```

Comment: do i need else statements for every if statement? other than that, you are right. It would be more accurate then.

Comment: it just depends on how you structure it you would not necessarily need else statments in my example 45 can only go in second block and it is <= 50 so would not go into third if block